# msysgit cannot pull tags

Tags: windows, git, msysgit

When doing a git pull on a project with GIT tags, I get the error below. 
I use msysgit on Win8, versions:

- git-gui version 0.19.GITGUI
- git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1
- Tcl/Tk version 8.5.13

The error I get is:

```
$ git pull --tags
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Me/.ssh/id_rsa':
fatal: Unable to create 'c:/Users/Me/someproject/.git/refs/remotes/origin/lpt1.2-support.lock': No such file or directory
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I think the ssh couldn't find your keys. Make sure they are in the default location.

1. Try to clone the remote. If you are not able to clone and you get the message "The remote end hung up unexpectedly". We can suspect that the your ssh key is not in the default location.
2. If you are able to clone, and couldn't pull check if you have any locks and the directory exist on your local. c:/Users/Me/someproject/.git/refs/remotes/origin/lpt1.2-support.lock
3. On msysgit, check if the variable HOME is set. HOME can be set to any directory you want, you only have to make sure you have the right to write in it (and that the directory exists and a .ssh under it exists too).
   ssh-keygen -t rsa
   And follow the prompts there.

If the problem is solved could you please let me know which of the three cases above helped you.

Comment: When cloning the repo again, I get asked for my SSH passphrase at '/c/Users/Me/.ssh/id_rsa', so thats OK

Comment: 2. I'm able to clone and then see all the tags. But:

    $ git checkout lpt1.2-support
    fatal: Unable to create 'c:/Users/Me/otherdir/someproject/.git/refs/heads/lpt1.2-support.lock': No such file or directory

Comment: 2. When I try to create a file with the path c:/Users/Me/otherdir/someproject/.git/refs/heads/lpt1.2-support.lock using the file browser, I get an error "The specified device name is invalid".

Comment: 3. I can create a new id_rsa_2 file in the $HOME/.ssh directory.